# Can we use Cross-Validation to estimate parameters?

Tags: multiple-regression, estimation, cross-validation

Suppose we are running a 10-Fold Cross Validation on a linear regression with 5 Variables (x1, ... , x5). In total we will have 10 fittings i.e. 10 sets of parameters β0, β1, ... , β5.

Could we use each ones average as an estimate for the model (i.e. β0est=avg(β0-1, β0-2, ..., β0-10) ?

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: @user20160 I was wondering whether it is an accurate way to calculate the parameter estimates. To me it seems reasonable but I am not 100% sure about it. That's why any opinion or proof on that would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *can* do that.  Since they are linear models, you are essentially averaging the predicted values from 10 linear models fit to slightly different slices of your training data.  You could imagine doing the same thing with bootstrap samples, and you'd have a linear-regression forest (but without the predictor subsampling that makes random forest work so well).

In the end, you get a crude sort of regularization out of the procedure.  The averaging lowers your model variance, but only to a point since there are only ten models and they are going to be quite correlated.

In practice, you have better options in penalized regularization methods.  These achieve the same ends, and give you more precise control over the variance reduction of the model.